# Checking if number is palindromic

Tags: python, palindrome

By passing user input as function call argument and using division.
I cannot understand where I am going wrong even when my logic is correct.

```
class Solution:

    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:

        x = int(input("Enter The number"))
        rev = 0
        while x > 0:
            temp = x % 10
            rev = (rev * 10 + temp)
            x = x // 10
        #print(rev)

        if x == rev:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    sol = Solution()
    a = sol.isPalindrome(x)
    print(a)
```

Comment: A class is unnecessary here and indented incorrectly, and `x` isn't defined outside the class, so the code shown has an error.  Recommend removing the class, the `self` parameter`, and moving the input request outside the function.

Comment: It's easier to convert the number to a string, and then check the string for palindrome-ness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can improve your code to function correctly, and also to be formatted a bit cleaner:

To fix your code, you need to make sure you aren't editing the value of `x`, but edit the value of another variable with the same value so that in your final comparison, you are comparing it to the actual value:

class Solution:

```
def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:

    x = int(input("Enter The number"))
    placehold = x
    rev = 0
    while placehold > 0:
        temp = placehold % 10
        rev = (rev * 10 + temp)
        placehold = placehold // 10
    #print(rev)

    if x == rev:
        return True
    else:
        return False


sol = Solution()
a = sol.isPalindrome(x)
print(a)
```

Secondly, there is no real reason here that you need to use a class. Using the function itself works just as well:

```
def isPalindrome():

    x = int(input("Enter The number"))
    placehold = x
    rev = 0
    while placehold > 0:
        temp = placehold % 10
        rev = (rev * 10 + temp)
        placehold = placehold // 10
    #print(rev)

    if x == rev:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(isPalindrome())
```

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite `x` in each iteration, so by the end of the loop it won't be equal to `rev`. You need to preserve is before starting any calculations of it. E.g.:

```
x = int(input("Enter The number"))
temp_x = x
rev = 0
while x > 0:
    temp = tepm_x % 10
    rev = (rev * 10 + temp)
    temp_x = temp_x // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that since you are changing `x` in your calculation of `rev`, your final statement:

```
if x == rev:
```

will always be `False` unless `x=0`

Instead, just create a copy of `x` and compare `rev` to that:

```
x = int(input("Enter The number"))
orig = x
rev = 0
while x > 0:
    temp = x % 10
    rev = (rev * 10 + temp)
    x = x // 10

if orig == rev:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

For the future, when you are trying to debug something, print out the variables that are changing (`rev` and `x`). This will help you catch errors like this in the future :)